NodeJS - read-only large JS Object shared amongst processes
I've been reading a lot about this issue but I can't come with a definite reliable solution. I know NodeJS spawns different instances as different CPU processes, hence sharing data or memory amongst processes is not trivial.
My webserver node application consumes a lot of memory (stores a large read-only JS Object for fast real-time delivery), but then I can't use all the available CPU cores, because the OS kills the extra processes.
I'd imagine a parent process would create a large JS Object into memory, from which children processes could only read.
I thought about:

databases such as Redis, but I would need serialization, which is not efficient for large Objects

the file system, which would not be a problem in terms of concurrency because it's read-only, but again, I would need serialization

unix sockets, serialization problem again


Hence, what is the most efficient way of reading large JS Object shared amongst NodeJS child processes?

Process memory can’t be shared

@DanielA.White ; OS or Node restrictions?

@DanielA.White what about this? https://www.makarenalabs.com/shared-memory-nodejs/
